# Using empty() on tbody keeps resizing width of entire table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery to reload data inside the `tbody`. However, the header column width keeps resizing event though I put the fixed width for the columns. I am using Firefox.

Simple HTML table:

```
<table style="width:95%;" border="1" align="center" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <td class="header" style="width:20%">ProductFamily
            <select onchange="selectCategoryChange()">
                <option "1">1</option>
                <option "2">2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td class="header" style="width:20%">ProductNum</td>
        <td class="header" style="width:30%">ProductDesc</td>
        <td class="header" style="width:5%">DT Rate</td>
        <td class="header" style="width:5%">List Rate</td>
        <td class="header" style="width:5%">Man Hour Unit</td>
        <td class="header" style="width:5%">Precall</td>
        <td class="header" style="width:5%">SOW</td>
        <td class="header" style="width:5%">Box</td>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody  id="tbodyDataRow">
        <!-- Data Rows Here -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When the tbody.empty(), it automatically resizes the width of the header columns, which make the page looks ugly. and then when I reload the new rows, it resize it back to original width. Here is my Jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    selectCategoryChange = function()
    {
        var tbody = $("#tbodyDataRow");
        tbody.empty();

    };
});
```

Comment: can you add a fiddle?

Comment: What your saying is that the HTML table is auto-resizing when you empty it of all content, right?

Comment: yes @colepanike,  basically, I have a dropdownlist on the header, and when onChange, it will empty the tbody, but the column width keep resizing..  thanks.

Comment: Here's a fiddle that shows the change. http://jsfiddle.net/s08oeqr3/2/

Comment: thanks @colepanike, yes, it changes when the tbody.enpty(). any ideas to make it not resize the column width?

Comment: in @colepanike fiddle the width of the elements are way smaller then the one for the class .header and one of your header is empty this is probably why its resizing.

Answer (score 1):

This works, but I've not tested it in all browsers. Change HTML to:

```
<table border="1" align="center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ProductNum</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>DT Rate</th>
            <th>List Rate</th>
            <th>Man Hour Unit</th>
            <th>Precall</th>
            <th>SOW</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbodyDataRow">
        <!-- tbody Content -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You should avoid inline styles anyway. Add this CSS file:

```
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.header {
    background-color: #ccc;
    font-weight: bold;
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

That'll fix your problem, but again it's not cross-browser tested. You might consider allowing the resize.

[Final result Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s08oeqr3/9/)

Comment: @codepanike, thanks for your time trying to help.  Sorry I wasn't clear.  I don't want the columns have the same width.  I have updated the HTML codes for the table.

Comment: You're attempting to break and HTML feature. The table cells will always try to adapt to the size of their content unless you give them hard constraints. I'm not sure there is a fix for this one. The real answer is that you shouldn't worry about the size of the columns and let them fit the data you put into them. Look here to see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/s08oeqr3/10/

Answer (score 0):

Your table `style="width:95%;"` is the problem. You are expecting a table with `8 X 200px = 1600px` width, but your table should has 95% as width, which can be more or less than 1600px. If it be deferent, the headers will be ajusted automatic. I'm sorry about my english.

Comment: Thanks for response. but even I put the % for column and make sure columns width added up to 100% of the table width, it still resizing when tbody gets empty().

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with empty() function applied on ul element. 
HTML structure :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <ul id="list"></ul>
    </td>
    <td>
     ...
    </td> 
  </tr>
```

I have a JS timer which call an ajax function responsible to refresh the content of the list (ul). To update the list (ul) I started to empty it with the following code:

```
$("#list").empty();
```

At each iteration, the column width was incremented even if content was the same. I finally replaced the content by the initial content by using replaceWith function and this time it was ok:

```
$("#list").replaceWith('<ul id="list"></ul>');
```